# ion-tabs keep showing highlighted bar on the bottom icon

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

this my tabs on browser :

[image]

and this my tabs on android platform :

[image]

can someone help me how to remove the highlighted bar?

Comment: put your code..!!log..!error..?

Comment: no error happen on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the documentation [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/provider/$ionicConfigProvider/), you should put this line of code;

```
$ionicConfigProvider.tabs.style('standard');
```